# How do I receive promise values in meteor for helper functions?

Tags: meteor, async-await, callback

I wanted to work with [Shopify's address library](https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/tree/master/packages/address). Since these work with promises I thought about implementing callbacks in order to receive the results

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict'
import AddressFormatter from '@shopify/address';

import './main.html';

const address = {
    company: 'Shopify',
    firstName: '恵子',
    lastName: '田中',
    address1: '八重洲1-5-3',
    address2: '',
    city: '目黒区',
    province: 'JP-13',
    zip: '100-8994',
    country: 'JP',
    phone: '',
};

Template.hello.onCreated(function () {
    const addressFormatter = new AddressFormatter('ja');
    const instance = this
    instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
    instance.state.setDefault('result', {
        "formattedAddress": "",
        "orderedFields": ""
    });

    getData(addressFormatter, function(r) {
        // the next line triggers the helper, since it "observes" the changes
        // to this "result" property on the reactive-dictionary
        instance.state.set('result', {
            formattedAddress: r.formattedAddress,
            orderedFields: r.orderedFields
        });
    });
})

Template.hello.helpers({
    address: function() {
        console.log(Template.instance().state.get("result"));
        return Template.instance().state.get('result')
    }
});

function getData(addressFormatter, callback) {
    const fa = async () => {
        const result = await addressFormatter.format(address);
        console.log(result)
        return result;
    }
    const of = async () => {
        const promise = addressFormatter.getOrderedFields('CA');
        promise.then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
    }
    let results = {
        "formattedAddress": fa(),
        "orderedFields": of()
    }
    callback(results);
}
```

The only thing that I receive in the template are `[object Promise]`. The console.logs in the getData() method actually show the accurate data but they are not displayed in teamplte. What can I do to receive the values and make my helper wait for them?

**Edit**: I have edited it according to @Jankapunkt answer but the objects are still empty, while the results in getData() are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. Helpers are there to immediately return values but are triggered by reactive data sources.

If you want a helper to "run" once the data "arrived" then your should move this code into `onCreated` and store the value in a reactive data source:

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveDict } from 'meteor/reactive-dict'
import AddressFormatter from '@shopify/address';

import './main.html';

const address = {
    company: 'Shopify',
    firstName: '恵子',
    lastName: '田中',
    address1: '八重洲1-5-3',
    address2: '',
    city: '目黒区',
    province: 'JP-13',
    zip: '100-8994',
    country: 'JP',
    phone: '',
};

Template.hello.onCreated(function () {
  const instance = this
  instance.state = new ReactiveDict()
  instance.state.setDefault('result', {
    "formattedAddress": "",
    "orderedFields": ""  
  })


  const addressFormatter = new AddressFormatter('ja')
  getData(addressFormatter)
    .then(({ formattedAddress, orderedFields }) => {
      // the next line triggers the helper, since it "observes" the changes
      // to this "result" property on the reactive-dictionary
      instance.state.set('result', { formattedAddress, orderedFields })
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e))

  return results;
})

Template.hello.helpers({
    address: function() {
      return Template.instance().state.get('result')
    }
});

const getData = async function (addressFormatter) {
  const formattedAddress = await addressFormatter.format(address)
  const orderedFields = await addressFormatter.getOrderedFields('CA')
  return {
    formattedAddress,
    orderedFields
  }
}
```

Readings: http://blazejs.org/

Edit: added a simplified `getData` that should work

Comment: Thank you, my bad. Changed it.

Comment: I have edited it regarding your suggestions but the objects are still empty while results in getData yield the correct and expected output :/

Comment: So `r` is returned in the callback but it's not displayed on the Template? Then you need to check your html, whether it correctly utilizes the values returned by `address`

Comment: I mean I just print out the result in the helper function and the object is already empty there (you can see the console.log in my edited post). And in my template I just access them like this   {{ address.formattedAddress }} {{ address.orderedFields }}. I know that they are dicts and need keys need to be accesses explicitly or entries need to be iterated over, but they are empty anyways

Comment: When do you expect to call `getData`?

Comment: Actually getData fires the callback immediately with the promises, there is no await.

Comment: thank you @ghybs I added a working `getData` implementation

Comment: That actually works, thank you @ghybs and @Jankapunkt!